# Disk quota increasing when adding files

Tags: maven, openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-cartridge, openshift-enterprise

I have 2 GB of disk space and I am uploading 2 jar files that both add up to a little less than 360 MB. But whenever I upload these JAR files with a couple other files (that are not even big) and whenever I push my code to upstream after editing it a bit, my disk quota reaches 100%. Why is this the case? How is the server automatically filling up each time I edit the code and especially after I add my jar files?

I am using maven to build the jar files and am aware that because of this, they both would be counted in two places. But 2 GB is more than enough, ins't it? So what is the problem? By the way, these jar files are 3rd party JAR files. AND I am using the wildly 10 cartridge.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: I read a post on open shift where it says that once you deploy your code (to the server), the git repository increases by that much. Does this mean that before deploying your code, you have to delete the previous code?

Comment: You can find what's eating up your space the most by sshing into your app `rhc ssh <appName>` and running something like `du -h * | sort -rh | head -50`. Here's more on this topic: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-filesystem.html#_resolving_disk_space_issues

Comment: I tried that and found that the` wildfly` folder itself is taking up the most space. It is taking 2 GB. The app-deployments is only taking 668 MB. And overtime I push my code, the wildfly folder size increases. Is there something that I am doing wrong or am not doing? Do I have to delete something (even though I only have configured my server to have one deployment)?

Comment: Try to force a clean deployment, create an empty file in `.openshift/markers`, i.e., `$ touch .openshift/markers/force_clean_build`

Comment: @JoãoGonçalves Thanks for the suggested solution. I made an empty file .openshift/markers/force_clean_build. Then, I tried to force clean build, but I got the following error message (after executing “rhc deploy master -a myapp —force-clean-build”): “CLIENT_MESSAGE: Failed deployments: ./ROOT.war”.